# Adding/changing sql metadata with firedac

Tags: delphi, metadata, firedac

Is there a way to add or change constraints (like primary keys, foreign keys, indexes, etc.) to an sql database with the TFDMetaInfoQuery from delphi firedac tools or the only thing I can do is extracting such information ?

something like : TFDMetaInfoQuery.AddConstraint or TFDMetaInfoQuery.AddPrimaryKey or TFDMetaInfoQuery.AddIndex - you get the point.

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Querying_Metadata_(FireDAC)) about using TFDMetaInfoQuery:

> The metadata dataset is read-only and cannot be edited.